# Determine letter based on row and col - python

Tags: python, string, letter

So I'm pretty upset I can't figure something this seemingly trivial out as I'm fairly well versed in Java, but anyways my professor for introduction to Python assigned us a lab where we have to create a pattern with letters based on row and column position. No loops or iterations, just conditional statements.

For instance, this function:

```
def letter(row, col):
   if row>col:
      return 'T'
   else:
      return 'W'
```

would yield:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTWWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTWWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTWWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTWWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTWWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTWWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTWWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTWWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTWWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTWWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTWWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTWW
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTW
```

if run through his driver file with row and col both equaling 20.

The one I'm stuck with is creating a function for the pattern:

```
XOOOOOX
OXOOOXO
OOXOXOO
OOOXOOO
OOXOXOO
OXOOOXO
XOOOOOX
```

Please do NOT spoonfeed me the answer, rather point me in the right direction.

So far I know that the X's for the left->right diagonal can be identified when row==col. It's the right->left diagonal I'm having issues with.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you clarify how the given function produces the given output - i.e., what is the "driver file" and how does one "run through" it?

Comment: In order to do the top-right -> bottom-left diagonal, you'll need to know the width (or height, since it's square).  In your example, it's 7.  That may be enough to get you started.

Comment: Oh, and does your professor consider recursion to be in the same category as loops? :P

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: It's pretty much got to be equivalent to `print('\n'.join(''.join(letter(row, col) for col in range(colcount)) for row in range(rowcount)))` (except maybe it shuffles the iteration to catch programs that accidentally or intentionally cheat with state…).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - Unfortunately I don't have access to the driver source code.

@jedwards - Thanks! I've actually solved it by stating that `if row==col or row+col==6 then return 'X'`. I'm not particularly happy with this though because I don't want to have to rely on using a constant. But the general formula is row+col=n+1.

Comment: Actually, speaking of "cheat with state"… I'm not sure how else you _do_ get the width/height? Either your program has to pass it to the driver, and you stash it in a global for `letter` to find, or `letter` keeps track of what it's seen so far and makes an assumption about the iteration order. So presumably one of those two doesn't count as "cheating".

Comment: @abarnert My guess is that you choose it, so you tell the driver `rowcount`/`colcount` and you write your code with that assumption.  At least that's what I got from "if run through his driver file with row and col both equaling 20."

Comment: One last thing: If you're really a lot more comfortable in Java, write a `public static char letter(int row, int col)` implementation, then try to port it to Python. As a general rule, that's a bad way to write code, but when you're stuck, it can be a way to get unstuck. (I've frequently written Ruby or JS code by writing it in nice Python, porting it as bad Ruby/JS, then once I get it, throwing it out and rewriting it as idiomatic Ruby/JS…)

Comment: @jedwards: Oh, duh, you're right, the answer is right there in the way the question is worded; I was overcomplicating things…

Comment: @abarnert that would be some next-level introduction to Python course though :)

Comment: @jedwards: "You may not use global variables. Hint: see `inspect.getsourcefile` and `ast.parse`". :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the relationship between the row and the column of each `X`'s position. Then, split this problem in two: one aspect of it is the line that goes from top-left to bottom-right, and the other aspect is the line that goes from bottom-left to top right.

Let's look at the top-left to bottom-right `X`s:

```
row: column:
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
```

I think you can determine a relationship between row and column based on that.

Now how about the other line, from bottom-left to top-right:

```
row: column:
1    7
2    6
3    5
4    4
5    3
6    2
7    1
```

Your gentle hint here is "+".

So, if an element's row and column have the first specified relationship `or` the second, you put an `X` there.

I hope that was a proper amount of help.

Comment: Great explanation. But I suspect `row` and `col` are 0-based, not 1-based. (Although the OP might learn something by working out what his code would do wrong if he guessed wrong each way, and then running it to verify…)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! This was a great answer, and I appreciate the gentle hint, haha!

Comment: I think that in this case the explanation is index-agnostic - it could've been `n`, `n+1`, etc. Also, I tested a function using this algorithm, running it through the driver you gave in that comment, and it behaved as expected. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Well, the code you have to write for 0-based vs. 1-based is going to be different here. But I guess you're right; to anyone who already understands the difference between 0-based and 1-based, your explanation will tell them all they need to know to write it either way.

Comment: That was the idea. :)